# making bootstrap vertical nav-pills automatical

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

**How i can make bootstrap 4 vertical nav-pills automatically by using javascript or jquery?**

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-3">
    <div class="nav flex-column nav-pills" id="v-pills-tab" role="tablist" aria-orientation="vertical">
      <a class="nav-link active" id="v-pills-home-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-home" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-home" aria-selected="true">Home</a>
      <a class="nav-link" id="v-pills-profile-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-profile" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-profile" aria-selected="false">Profile</a>
      <a class="nav-link" id="v-pills-messages-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-messages" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-messages" aria-selected="false">Messages</a>
      <a class="nav-link" id="v-pills-settings-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-settings" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-settings" aria-selected="false">Settings</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-9">
    <div class="tab-content" id="v-pills-tabContent">
      <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="v-pills-home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-home-tab">...</div>
      <div class="tab-pane fade" id="v-pills-profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-profile-tab">...</div>
      <div class="tab-pane fade" id="v-pills-messages" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-messages-tab">...</div>
      <div class="tab-pane fade" id="v-pills-settings" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-settings-tab">...</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you please explain more about what is the problem and what the goal is?

Comment: OP wants to [to this](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/navs/#tabs). If you [include the proper resources](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/getting-started/introduction/) it should _"just work."_ Here's an example [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/68ugsLwb/).

Comment: I want make those bootstrap4 tab automatically by using JS or jQuery only, in static it's available in official bootstrap navs website but i want make hem automatical, i want this [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35212808/bootstrap-vertical-tabs-auto-change/35214747] but for bootstrap4 not 3

Comment: thank you @hungerstar , how i can automatic this code in cycle, means automatically go to tab 1 and content 1 after 3 second or 5 second automatically go to tab 2 and content 2? by javascript or jquery

Comment: Ah, you want it to behave like an automated image slider/gallery. I would update your terminology to something like that in your post as it's not obvious what _"automatical"_ is referring to.

Comment: yes like as you said, as the image slider please, jquery or javascipt can make this automatic

Comment: @hungerstar you understand my question? can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To automate the selection of a panel like a an automated slider/image gallery you will need to fake clicking on each tab (pill) link.

The basics are:

- Add something to the markup that signifies that this is a *"tab slider."* In this case, a `data-` attribute.
- Loop the collection and instantiate each tab slider. For each tab slider:

  - Get a reference to each tab.
  - Count the tabs - for use with Modulo operator (`%1`) and incrementor variable to determine which panel to display.
  - Create a function that can get called repeatedly, `setTimeout`, that will advance to the next panel by triggering a click event on a tab.

```js
$( '[data-widget="tab-slider"]' ).each( function ( i, el ) {

  const $container   = $( this );
  const $sliderLinks = $container.find( '.nav-link' );
  const panelCount   = $sliderLinks.length;
  const delay        = 3000; // milleseconds
  let   index        = 0;

  function nextTabSliderPanel() {

    $sliderLinks.eq( index++ % panelCount ).trigger( 'click' );
    setTimeout( nextTabSliderPanel, delay );

  }
  
  nextTabSliderPanel(); // Start the slider.

} );
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script><script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="row" data-widget="tab-slider">
  <div class="col-3">
    <div class="nav flex-column nav-pills" id="v-pills-tab" role="tablist" aria-orientation="vertical">
      <a class="nav-link active" id="v-pills-home-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-home" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-home" aria-selected="true">Home</a>
      <a class="nav-link" id="v-pills-profile-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-profile" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-profile" aria-selected="false">Profile</a>
      <a class="nav-link" id="v-pills-messages-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-messages" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-messages" aria-selected="false">Messages</a>
      <a class="nav-link" id="v-pills-settings-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-settings" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-settings" aria-selected="false">Settings</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-9">
    <div class="tab-content" id="v-pills-tabContent">
      <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="v-pills-home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-home-tab">Home Panel</div>
      <div class="tab-pane fade" id="v-pills-profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-profile-tab">Profile Panel</div>
      <div class="tab-pane fade" id="v-pills-messages" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-messages-tab">Messages Panel</div>
      <div class="tab-pane fade" id="v-pills-settings" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-settings-tab">Settings Panel</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```